# Html canvas to Image with css Transition

Tags: php, html, image, html5-canvas

I am trying to make a image sticker html 5 app. In which user uploads a photo and then places stickers on top of it. I am able to do it through HTML 5 canvas and Jquery library free transform to rotate and scale stickers on top of image but when i convert this into jpeg the css transaction is lost and only image with stickers on top is generated. Code is written below. Is there any other way to do it?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Video</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.21/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"/> 

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui-touch-punch/0.2.3/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://greenethumb.com/github/jquery-free-transform/css/jquery.freetrans.css"/> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://greenethumb.com/github/jquery-free-transform/js/Matrix.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://greenethumb.com/github/jquery-free-transform/js/jquery.freetrans.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.ui.core.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.ui.resizable.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="html2canvas.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="FileSaver.js"></script>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1"  />
<style>
#draggable-zone {
    background: #000 url(images/space.jpg) 0 0 no-repeat;
    border:     3px solid #000;
    height:     500px;
    margin:     2em auto;
    overflow:   hidden;
    width:      600px;
    }

.ui-wrapper {
    overflow:   visible !important;}

.ui-resizable-handle {
    background:    #f5dc58;
    border:        1px solid #FFF;

    z-index:    2;}

.ui-rotatable-handle {
    background:    #f5dc58;
    border:        1px solid #FFF;
    border-radius: 5px;
        -moz-border-radius:    5px;
        -o-border-radius:      5px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    cursor:        pointer;

    height:        10px;
    left:          50%;
    margin:        0 0 0 -5px;
    position:      absolute;
    top:           -5px;
    width:         10px;}

.ui-rotatable-handle.clone {
    visibility:  hidden;}
</style>
</head>
<body>




                      <div id="imagediv" style="width:400px;" >

                      <div style="width:400px;border:1px solid #000;position:relative" >
                         <img src="lordmeowington.png" width="400px">

                                    <div id="draggable-wrapper"  style="position:absolute;top:0">
                                        <div id="resizable-wrapper">                
                                            <img src="funny_glasses.png" width="150" height="150" alt=" " id="elem-wrapper" />
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                         </div>

                        </div>

                              <input type="button"   value="saveimage"  onclick="demoFromHTML()" />           
                              <input type="button"   value="remove"  onclick="  Demo()" />      

                              <input type="file" accept="image/*" capture="camera" />
                          <input type="text" value="" id="innerimage" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/ui/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/ui/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/ui/jquery.ui.mouse.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/ui/jquery.ui.draggable.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/ui/jquery.ui.resizable.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/ui/jquery.ui.rotatable.js"></script>
<script>


$(document).ready(function() {
        var drWr = $('#draggable-wrapper'),
            rsWr = $('#resizable-wrapper'),
            elem = $('#elem-wrapper');

        elem.resizable({
            aspectRatio: true,
            handles:     'ne, nw, se, sw'
        });

        drWr.draggable();

        elem.parent().rotatable();
    });


function Demo()
{
$('.ui-rotatable-handle').css('border','0px');
$('.ui-resizable-handle').css('background','none');
$('.ui-resizable-handle').css('border','none');
$('.ui-rotatable-handle').css('background','none');
html2canvas($("#imagediv"), {
            onrendered: function(canvas) {         
                var imgData = canvas.toDataURL(
                    'image/jpeg');
            imgData.width=400;                  
              console.log(imgData); 
              var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
            ajax.open("POST",'testSave.php',false);
            ajax.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/upload');
            ajax.send(imgData);
             //window.open(imgData);
            }
        });

}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Php Code is below

```
<?php
if (isset($GLOBALS["HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA"]))
{

  $imageData=$GLOBALS['HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA'];
  $filteredData=substr($imageData, strpos($imageData, ",")+1);
  $unencodedData=base64_decode($filteredData);
  $fp = fopen( 'test.png', 'wb' );
  fwrite( $fp, $unencodedData);
  fclose( $fp );
}
?>
```

Comment: **Html2Canvas does not yet support CSS transformations.** The workaround is to draw directly on the canvas itself. Canvas has transformations (.rotate, .scale, etc) that allow you to properly position your elements.

Comment: and what about the sticker.. will the sticker be in this new rectangle? can you show me an example or reffer me to one ..Thanks